# how to sort pandas groups based on an aggregate

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe df and used groupby on it. How can I sort these groups? I would like to have the group with the highest median in column B first, the one with lowest median last.
I know how to get the median sorted:

```
df.groupby(by='A')['B'].median().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

But how would I actually sort the groups (not their median)?

Comment: groups are alpha sorted by default. You can elect not to sort like this `df.groupby('A', sort=False)` which results in slightly better performance.

Comment: And there is no way to get groups sorted differently? I am preparing a boxplot here, so I want to have one group per box and still I want to change the position of boxes on the x axis (precisely, I want to sort them by 'importance' which is given in this column B)

Comment: That means that you are sorting by values, as demonstrated by @EdChum below.

Comment: Have you also read my comment to his demonstration? I want to sort the groups the way he did, but I would still like to have all values inside each group, not just the median. I don't know how that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` from the result of `sort_values` to index the group:

```
In [118]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df['group'] = list('aabcc')
df

Out[118]:
          a         b         c group
0  3.260645 -0.636861  0.183312     a
1 -0.409939  1.915902 -2.426166     a
2 -0.522152  1.621288  0.225874     b
3  0.576484  0.499148 -1.037899     c
4  0.626081  0.040262 -1.679669     c

In [128]:    
gp = df.groupby('group')['a'].median()
gp

Out[128]:
group
a    1.425353
b   -0.522152
c    0.601282
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [134]:
order = gp.sort_values(ascending=False)
order

Out[134]:
group
a    1.425353
c    0.601282
b   -0.522152
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [135]:    
gp[order.index]

Out[135]:
group
a    1.425353
c    0.601282
b   -0.522152
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the sort order based on median you can add the median column back to the orig df using `transform` and then sort the original df:

```
In [7]:
df['median'] = df.groupby('group')['a'].transform('median')
df

Out[7]:
          a         b         c group    median
0  3.260645 -0.636861  0.183312     a  1.425353
1 -0.409939  1.915902 -2.426166     a  1.425353
2 -0.522152  1.621288  0.225874     b -0.522152
3  0.576484  0.499148 -1.037899     c  0.601282
4  0.626081  0.040262 -1.679669     c  0.601282

In [9]:    
df.loc[df['median'].sort_values(ascending=False).index]

Out[9]:
          a         b         c group    median
1 -0.409939  1.915902 -2.426166     a  1.425353
0  3.260645 -0.636861  0.183312     a  1.425353
4  0.626081  0.040262 -1.679669     c  0.601282
3  0.576484  0.499148 -1.037899     c  0.601282
2 -0.522152  1.621288  0.225874     b -0.522152
```

Comment: Thanks, this points in the right direction.
However, it does not answer my complete question as in the end, (out[135]) it is still the medians that are sorted not the groups. I.e. I would like to do something like `df.groupby('group')[order.index]` to sort the groups (and all their values) but this does not work for me ('Columns not found'). Any suggestions?

Comment: @brina Suggestion: add a column with a group median, sort `df` by it, and then group again with `sort=False`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are looking for the groups sorted by the medians.

If that is the case, you can use:

```
df.groupby(by='A')['B'].median().sort_values(ascending=False).index
```

Comment: thanks for answering this but given that my original question is more than 2 years old, I don't remember the details myself anymore (nor where I now have the code that I could use to try this)...

Comment: I understand. The reason I placed my reply was to provide a solution for others facing a similar problem - like me, a couple of days ago!